# Flutter awesome_notification actionButton is not showing when the app is terminated

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-dependencies

Im using firebase and awesome notification package.

firebase_core: ^2.20.0
firebase_messaging: ^14.7.2
awesome_notifications_core: ^0.8.1 # <~ always ensure to use the latest version
awesome_notifications: any

Flutter awesome_notification actionButton is not showing when the app is terminated.

It shows when the app is at foreground and background.

These are my code.

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  AwesomeNotificationHelper.createNewNotification(message);

  return Future<void>.value();
}

static Future<void> createNewNotification(RemoteMessage message) async {
    RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
    bool isAllowed = await AwesomeNotifications().isNotificationAllowed();

    if (!isAllowed || notification == null) return;

    await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
      content: NotificationContent(
        id: -1,
        channelKey: 'alerts',
        title: notification.title,
        body: notification.body,
        payload: {'notificationId': '1234567890'}),
      actionButtons: [
        NotificationActionButton(
          key: 'Redirect',
          label: 'Redirect',
        ),
        NotificationActionButton(
          key: 'REPLY',
          label: 'Reply Message',
          requireInputText: true,
          actionType: ActionType.SilentAction,
        ),
        NotificationActionButton(
          key: 'DISMISS',
          label: 'Dismiss',
          actionType: ActionType.DismissAction,
          isDangerousOption: true,
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```